# How to update Chinese fonts on a Kindle Paperwhite registered at US Amazon?

Tags: kindle, fonts, kindle-paperwhite

Recently Amazon rolled out an update to Kindle Paperwhite(Generation 1) which added functionalities like vocabulary review, which are nice. However, one big problem I'm having is that it somehow deleted the *KaiTi（楷体）* Chinese font it originally had, leaving only *SongTi（宋体）* and *Heiti（黑体）* as possible choices. Those fonts have a very tight line spacing which makes for a difficult reading experience.

I read from users who register at Chinese Amazon that the updated Kindle Paperwhite should automatically download *KaiTi（楷体）* and *YuanTi（圆体）* once it's connected to network. However it's not happening to me. If I have to deregister my Kindle and re-register it at Chinese Amazon just for the sake of fonts, it'll be quite a pain, not to mention I'll probably have to re-download all the books I have in US Amazon account, plus the potential loss of some reading progress. Therefore, is there some way to update the Chinese fonts on a Kindle PW which is registered at US Amazon? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well OK I somehow found the answer myself... The problem of Chinese fonts not updating is not because of my registration at US Amazon, but because of my system font not being Chinese... As soon as I changed my font to Chinese it almost immediately started the font update.

Comment: If you change your comment into an answer I will upvote it for you. There is no reason why you can't answer your own question officially (you can even accept your own answer after 2 days... you just don't get the usual reputation associated with it).

Comment: @JasonDown I wanted to do it. However the system prevented me from doing so within eight hours of posting this question, because I'm a user below 10 reputation. So I'll turn it into an answer after 8 hours have passed.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well OK I somehow found the answer myself. The problem of Chinese fonts not updating is not because of my registration at US Amazon, but because of my system font not being Chinese. As soon as I changed my font to Chinese it almost immediately started the font update.

Comment: I wish that was the case. My Chinese and Japanese fonts use to repeatedly update without my consent.

Comment: @743 I'm not sure whether it's the same issue that you have...

Comment: my problem was the opposite. I was getting Chinese and Japanese font update's without my consent (on a older version)